# Guake behavior for other apps

Tags: 12.04, gvim, guake

I use and love the guake terminal emulator, so I wonder if it is possible to get the toggle behavior to work for other applications.

For example I want to press F11 and my current running gVim instance should pop in in a defined location (or fullscreen). But it would already be helpful to switch to gVim and give it focus.

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with the commandline tool `wmctrl` as follows:

Install `wmctrl` (`sudo apt-get install wmctrl`)

Create a shell script to toggle between two vim positions: The position I want vim to show up and a position out of sight (like a virtual desktop). You get get the required positions with `wmctrl -l -G`.

```
TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle_vim 
if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    wmctrl -r GVIM -e "0, 1748, 549,  1612, 484"
else
    rm $TOGGLE
    wmctrl -r GVIM -e "0, 3227, 1050, 132,  76"
fi
```

Map that script as custom keyboard shortcut: "bash /path/to/script"